# Sharepoint Button to run Power Automate Flow not working on Page

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a button that activates a Power Automate Flow using the "For selected Item" trigger.  This works perfectly fine from the View of the List Items.  However when I add that very same view onto a Sharepoint Page the button is not working?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using JSON formatting for creating button inside list view to run flow?

Comment: Yes I am using JSON formatting

Comment: Can you share the JSON? It might be the limitation of SharePoint JSON formatting that some actions do not work in list web part on site pages.

Comment: Sure - here it the JSON formatting I use

Comment: {"$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json","elmType":"button","customRowAction":{"action":"executeFlow","actionParams":"{\"id\": \"b777e286-172b-4b3b-8620-4f1f9cce907e\"}"},"attributes":{"class":"ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"},"style":{"background-color":"#008082","color":"white","border-radius":"0 15px","cursor":"pointer"},"children":[{"elmType":"span","attributes":{"iconName":"KnowledgeArticle"},"style":{"padding-right":"6px"}},{"elmType":"span","txtContent":"Create Agenda"}]}

Comment: Ok. This is a known limitation of SharePoint Online JSON formatting. `executeFlow` action does not work while using the list web part on SharePoint site pages. Check more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of SharePoint Online JSON formatting.

`executeFlow` and `editProps` actions don't work while using the list web part on SharePoint site pages.

> I can confirm that the Launch Flow and Edit Props actions don't work when using the list web part. I'd call that a bug since it wasn't called out as unsupported anywhere that I've seen.

Check more information at: [Create a button to launch a Flow not working in list/library web part on page](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6397)

**Similar thread**: [How to use Column Formatting in SharePoint Home Page?](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/issues/606)